# iOS 8 - animate showing navigation and status bars not working correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, ios8

I am trying to have the navigation and status bar slide into view together. In previous iOS versions, the following code worked perfectly:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:YES];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

Is iOS 8, this causes the animation of the Navigation bar to slide down too far and then bounce back.
I can solve the problem by removing the animation for the status bar and showing it instantly. However this doesn't look nearly as nice.

Has anyone else encountered this problem or know of a fix?

Thanks!

Comment: You gotta love Apple and their policy of dumping partially tested (untested?) software on unsuspecting users and developer... And you gotta love the "File a RADAR" even more...

Answer (score 3):

Well, I found the solution. Change the order of the animation.

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:YES];
```